# Trying to get user data in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

OK I'm still a beginner, and i have alot to learn. Still in my first programming class and was wondering if i could get some help on an assignmet. **I DON'T WANT YOU TO DO IT FOR ME** just some help. I'm supposed to making a lottery type game using arrays and functions. Here's what i have so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<random>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

void getPlayersNumbers(int playerArray[], int size);
void getComputersNumbers(int computerArray[], int size);
bool WinningNumber(int playerArray[], int computerArray[], int size);

int main() {

const int SIZE = 5;
int userNumbers[SIZE];
int computerNumbers[SIZE];


getComputersNumbers(computerNumbers, SIZE);

return 0;

}

void getPlayersNumbers(int playerArray[], int size) {

int playersNumbers;

cout << "Please enter 5 numbers for a chance to win!!\n";

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   cin >> ???
}


}

void getComputersNumbers(int computerArray[], int size) {

mt19937 randomGenerator(time(0));
uniform_int_distribution<int> randomNumbers(1, 5);

int computerNumbers;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    computerNumbers = randomNumbers(randomGenerator);
    computerArray[i] = computerNumbers;
    cout << computerNumbers << " ";
}
cout << endl;
}

bool winningNumbers(int playerArray[], int computerArray[], int size) {

}
```

My `getComputerNumbers` function is working just fine. The one I'm having trouble with is my `getPlayerNumbers` function. How would i go about getting the uses numbers from them, and keeping them so when i call the function i can compare them to the random numbers in my `getComputerNumbers` function? Now i already know how I'm going to go about comparing the numbers. That's what my that third function `winningNumbers` is for. I just Need help with the `getPlayersNumbers`.
Also if you see anything else that i can do to make this code better let me know.
Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store user's number into an array:

```js
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   cin >> userNumbers[i]
}
```

when you want to access a particular number out of the five, you use:
`userNumbers[n]`, where n ranges from 0 to 4

Comment: awesome! Now i know how to compare to see if all the generated numbers match the user input numbers. So would i use userNumbers[n] to check if only a few of the numbers match, if they don't all match at first?

Comment: You can use a a break statement to stop the "checking" when the number you are currently checking is not the same as the generator number

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
 void getPlayersNumbers(int* playerArray, int size) 
 { 
       cout << "Please enter 5 numbers for a chance to win!!\n";
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
            cin >> playerArray [i];
        } 
  }
```

Thanks to @user4581301 for pointing out a better solution using  std::vector

```
 std::vector getPlayersNumbers(int size) 
 { 
       std::vector myNumberList;
       cout << "Please enter 5 numbers for a chance to win!!\n";
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
            int number;
            cin >> number;
            myNumberList.push_back (number);
        }

        return  myNumberList;
  }
```

STL makes working with arrays a whole lot easier and also it provides additional functions that are optimized for their use case

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. std::vector is a very good option